# Laravel 5.4 Upgrade - ReflectionException: Class session does not exist

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I updated my local environment to use Laravel 5.4, and in doing so, I can no longer run any tests using phpunit.

The error I am getting is:

```
ApplicationTest::testEnvironment
ReflectionException: Class session does not exist

/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/sa4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:681
/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/sa4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:565
/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/sa4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:105
/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/sa4/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:780
/home/vagrant/Code/Sites/sa4/tests/TestCase.php:30
```

Anyone know of a solution for this? I've hit a brick wall :(

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the code that uses `session` within your tests?

Comment: public function setTimezone()
        {
            session()->put('timezone', config('sa.default_timezone'));
        }

That is in my TestCase.php file and that is where the problems begin in the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have used somewhere `session` instead of `Session` facade (capital `S`)

Comment: I was able to track the problem down to the session() helper no longer working correctly. I'm thinking I might have missed something in the update that needed to be done. *ponder*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that cache directory exists inside bootstrap.

Comment: This can cause Laravel to throw the OP's session error. It has to /bootstrap/cache must exist and be writable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error after switching to a Git branch that was still on an older version of Laravel (Laravel 8 instead of Laravel 9 on the master branch). Doing `composer install` (*not* `composer upgrade`, which will update the dependencies in your lockfile and potentially break your app) and `npm run dev` was enough to solve the issue for me.